# Convert an HTML string to a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, file

I have an HTML string which is guaranteed to only contain text (i.e. no images, videos, or other assets). However, just to note, there might be formatting with some of the text like some of them might be bold.

Is there a way to convert the HTML string output to a .txt file? I don't care about maintaining the formatting but I do want to maintain the spacing of the text.

Is that possible with Python?

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
import html2text
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/page.html').read())

txt = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'body'})

print(html2text.html2text(txt))
```

Comment: Please add formatting to your code snippet.